# Max date before current quarter in SQL query

Tags: sql, datetime, vertica

Create new field - `Max` date before current quarter

```
Q1 Nov-Jan
Q2 Feb-Apr
Q3 May-Jul
Q4 Aug-Oct
```

Quarters are as above

```
Select Product_ID,
Max(Date(Sales_Date)) as Max_Sales_date
From Table1 A
where Sales_Date='01/31/2019' (not Harcode)
Group by Product_ID

Select Product_ID,
Max(Date(Sales_Date)) as Max_Sales_date
From Table1 A
where Sales_Date='01/31/2019' (not Harcode)
Group by Product_ID
```

Comment: "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.  Which _database_ are you actually using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Please briefly mention you requirements.

Comment: I need to pull the data from vertica and create table in SQL DB

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Two things: 1) please [edit] your question to explain your requirement more thoroughly. 2) You should know that date / time processing in SQL isn't standardized. To help you we need to know which make and model of SQL table server you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, looking similar query like this

Select Product_ID,
Max(Date(Sales_Date)) as Max_Sales_date
From Table1 A
where Sales_Date <= 
       case 
                when  (month(getdate()) in ('2','3','4') and year(getdate()) = '2019') then  '01/31/2019'
                when  (month(getdate()) in ('5','6','7') and year(getdate()) = '2019') then '04/30/2019'
                when  (month(getdate()) in ('8','9','10') and year(getdate()) = '2019') then  '07/30/2019'
                when  (month(getdate()) in ('11','12','1') and year(getdate()) in ('2019','2020')) then '10/31/2019'
                end
Group by Product_ID;

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an expression like this?

```
date_trunc('quarter', current_date) - interval '1 day'
```